# Client does not gets reconnected once the client leaves the room or disconnects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webrtc, kurento

I am using Kurento client for video calling in a room. There is only two participants(local and remote) in a call. A client can leave the room but when a client leaves the room then the stream of that client is not shown to other client which is obvious but when again that same client wants to join in the room, the client does not gets connected because of which the other client wont see his/her stream to have video call.

Here is how i have done

```
import kurentoUtils from "kurento-utils";
import socketIOClient from "socket.io-client";
import {
  createWebRTCPeer,
  sendMessage,
  createWebRTCScreenPeer
} from "./common";

const CONSTRAINTS = {
  audio: true,
  video: {
    width: 640,
    framerate: 15
  }
};

class VideoRoom extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      startCall: false,
      room: "",
      clientJoined: false,
      email: "",
      isLoggedIn: false,
      open: false,
      mute: false
    };
    this.localStreamRef = React.createRef();
    this.remoteStreamRef = React.createRef();
    this.onIceCandidates = this.onIceCandidates.bind(this);
    this.handleError = this.handleError.bind(this);
    this.socket = null;
    this.webRTC = null;
    this.loginName = null;
  }

  handleError = (e)=> {
    console.log(e);
  }

  onIceCandidates(candidate) {
    sendMessage(
      {
        event: "iceCandidate",
        data: candidate
      },
      this.socket
    );
  }


  componentDidMount() {
    this.socket = new socketIOClient("http://localhost:8443/sockets");
    this.webRtcPeer = null;
    this.webRtcScreenPeer = null;
    const { state } = this.props.location;
    if (state && state.interviewId) {
      this.initiateSocket();
    }
  }


  initiateSocket() {
    const { interviewId } = this.props.location.state;
    this.socket.emit("room:addUser", { interviewId, userEmail: this.state.email });

    this.socket.on("ICE_CANDIDATE", async candidate => {
      console.log("candidate in listener", candidate);
      await this.webRTC.addIceCandidate(candidate);
    });

    this.socket.on("RTC:PEER", room => {
      console.log("RTC:PEER", room, this.localStreamRef);
      this.webRtcPeer = createWebRTCPeer(
        {
          localVideo: this.localStreamRef.current,
          remoteVideo: this.remoteStreamRef.current,
          onicecandidate: this.onIceCandidates
        },
        this.socket,
        room
      );
    });

    this.socket.on("client:joined", () => {
      this.setState({ clientJoined: true });
    });

    this.socket.on("iceCandidate", (candidate) => {
      console.log("GOT Candidate....");
      this.webRtcPeer.addIceCandidate(candidate);
    });

    this.socket.on("answer", answer => {
      console.log("GOT ANSWER....");
      this.webRtcPeer.processAnswer(answer);
    });

    this.socket.on("remote:leave", () => {
      console.log("LEAVE FROM REMOTE");
      this.handleLeaveRoom(true);
      this.setState({ clientJoined: false });
    });

    this.socket.on("ERROR", error => this.onError(error));
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.socket.emit('end');
    this.socket = null;
    this.webRtcPeer && this.webRtcPeer.dispose();
    this.webRtcPeer = null;
  }

  onError = error => console.error(error);

  handleLeaveRoom = (remote = false) => {
    if (remote) {
      this.remoteStreamRef.current.srcObject = null;
    } else if (
      this.webRtcPeer !== null &&
      this.webRtcPeer !== undefined &&
      this.socket !== null
    ) {
      this.localStreamRef.current.srcObject = null;
      this.props.history.push("/interivew-id");
    } else {
      return ;
    }
  };

  render() {

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Wrapper>
          <Studio
            {...this.state}
            interviewer={this.localStreamRef}
            interviewee={this.remoteStreamRef}
          />
          <Controls
            handleLeaveRoom={() => this.handleLeaveRoom()}
            handleMute={() => this.handleMute()}
            mute={this.state.mute}
            handleScreenShare={this.handleScreenShare}
          />
        </Wrapper>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(VideoRoom);
```

server.js

```
socket.on("end", () => {
    console.log(`closing socket in room:: ${socket.room}`);
    // console.log(`socket end: room: ${room ? room : socket.room}`)
    socket.disconnect(0);
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log("Client disconnected from", socket.room);
    let session = sessions[socket.room];
    if(session){
      session.removeClient(socket.id);
    }
    socket.broadcast.to(socket.room).emit('remote:leave', socket.id);
  });
```

Here is the full code

https://gist.github.com/SanskarSans/76aee1ab4ccab7c02dc812019f1329e9

The leave room works but when trying to re join, the client does not gets connected and show his/her stream to remote client.

Comment: Any errors? Does the socket get connected successfully?